# Makefiles, "configure" files, and other compilation tools -- How do they work? Why do they work the way they do?

Tags: mingw, configure, makefile

I'm still new to the UNIX/Linux world, and, in particular, to related tools, such as the GCC compiler. Namely, I'm still new to makefiles and things like that (I use MinGW on Windows), since so far, most of my development has been with IDEs like Visual Studio and Eclipse.

When I open a typical project folder, I see files like these:

```
configure
make
INSTALL
install-sh  (or a variant)
```

There's quite a few things I don't understand here, and my main questions are these:

1. What's the difference between these, and why do we need each one? (In the IDE world, all you have is a project file; that's it. So I'm confused why we have more than just a makefile here.)
2. How are these files generated? For small projects, you could probably write them by hand, but for big projects like GCC, it would be ridiculous to even try. I've found editing these files to be a pain, and I've come to the conclusion that I'm not supposed to be modifying them by hand. But if so, then what tools do people typically use for adding and modifying these files?
3. Why don't they use wildcards inside a makefile? Why is there a single line for every single object file? Is this because of a restriction, or is there an advantage to it?
4. What's the difference between having a shell script that calls the compiler with every file, and having a *makefile* that does the same thing? In Windows, I'd be very tempted to just create a batch file inside the folder, and compile everything with that -- no need for more than just one file. What's the difference? Why isn't there just a single `.sh` file, to compile everything?

Bonus question:

- Is there a "standard" makefile format? I've seen different `make` tools that don't accept each other's formats... how do I know what to use? Is GCC just the usual tool here, or is there some standard everyone should follow?

I'll probably have more questions as I learn more about the structure of projects like this, but for now, these are my biggest questions. :)

Comment: There are tools such as automake that generate some of these files for you. `configure` generally looks at the current system and modifies how the program is built to suit the system. Separate files are given separate lines for several reasons. Only if a file has been modified will it be recompiled. Different instances of gcc can run on different processors or even different machines with tools like distcc. I'm sure there are other reasons, too. Make just handles compiling the source files (usually) with installing (copying to the final destination) left as a separate step.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. In your average package, those files each have an individual purpose. This is concordant with the unix philosophy of "each program should do one thing and do that thing well". In most projects, you'll see files like:

   - `configure`
   - `configure.ac`
   - `Makefile`
   - `Makefile.in`
   - `Makefile.am`
   - `install-sh`
   - `INSTALL`

   `configure` is (usually) a shell script that checks your system for all required features before building anything. `Makefile.in` is a template for a `Makefile`. The results of the configure tests are substituted into `Makefile.in` to generate `Makefile`. This is to deal with people having things (compilers, headers, libraries) in obscure paths, cross-compiling (e.g., building for ARM on x86), optional library support (some programs have additional features that can be switched on or off), compiling with different options, and so on. Writing a one-size-fits-all `Makefile` is actually *really hard*.

   As you've noticed, the `configure` script itself is a mess. It's not meant to be seen by mortal eyes, nor edited by mortal hands. It's actually the result of compiling `configure.ac`, using a program called `autoconf`. `autoconf` is a package of macros for and a wrapper around the `m4` macro processor, which was about the only good tool for this sort of thing at the time (`autoconf` is really quite old software, but has aged remarkably well). `autoconf` lets the developer easily write tests to check for headers, libraries or programs that are required to build the software (and this changes from program to program).

   If you dig a little deeper, you'll notice that `Makefile.in` also tends to be a little ugly. This is because writing good `Makefile`s is often a lot of boilerplate, and that's inspired another tool, `automake`. `automake` compiles `Makefile.am` (which is often short and declarative) into `Makefile.in` (which is enormous), which is then compiled into `Makefile` by `configure` (essentially).

   `install-sh` is a script that is distributed with `automake` but copied into other packages. It exists as a replacement if the version of `install` on the system is crap (`install` copies files into the installation directory. Some really old systems had broken versions of `install`, and `automake` is pretty conservative about dropping warnings for old systems). Some other scripts that fulfil similar roles are `compile`, `depcomp` and `ylwrap`.

   `INSTALL` is just a document that describes how to install the package. It's usually boilerplate content copied into the package by `automake`.
2. I've answered this inline above, but here is the summary:

   - `configure.ac ==[autoconf]=> configure`
   - `Makefile.am ==[automake]=> Makefile.in ==[configure]=> Makefile`

   Where the program responsible is inside the arrow. To understand this in detail, I recommend this [autotools tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html). Don't be put off by the page count, most of it is diagrams appearing piece by piece.
3. Wildcards in `Makefile`s are sometimes used. GNU Make, for example, supports a `$(wildcard)` function, where you can write something like:

   `SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.c)`

   The main reason features like `$(wildcard)` aren't used is that they are extensions, and `automake` tries very hard to generate `Makefile`s that will work with *any* POSIX-compliant `make`. After a project becomes mature, the list of files to compile doesn't change all that much, anyway.

   A second reason files are listed explicitly is when programs get optional features. Wildcards are no longer appropriate, and you instead have to list the conditions under which additional features are to be compiled in.
4. A `Makefile` tracks dependencies between files, where a shell script cannot (not without significant effort, anyway).

If you have a `Makefile` rule like:

```
foo.out: foo.in
        generate-foo foo.in
```

It tells `make` that if `foo.in` is *newer* than `foo.out`, a new `foo.out` can be created by executing `generate-foo foo.in`. This saves lots of redundant work on big projects, where you might only change one or two files between recompilations.

Your bonus question appears a little ill-posed. The most common `make` is probably GNU Make, although I'd guess that the BSD make would be a close second, followed by the various proprietary `make` versions supplied with Solaris, AIX and so on.

These all accept the same basic structure in `Makefile` (because POSIX says so), but might have vendor-specific extensions to the syntax.

GCC is not a build tool like `make`. GCC is a command-line compiler, akin to `cl.exe` on windows.

Comment: That was a really good explanation of everything, and it makes a lot of sense. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of reasons for different things, but in the end it boils down to portability.  During the unix wars, every platform was different, and people tried to make software that would work on as many as possible.  So common denominators had to be found. sh was one such commonality, so configure scripts were written to use maximally portable sh.  Maximal portability implies using a minimal set of features.  Different implementations of make vary greatly in the features they support, so Makefiles were written that used as few features as possible.  Things are slightly better today, but portability concerns still drive a lot of the things you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

1. `configure` is a script that sets up the build environment and possibly generates the makefile. With `make` you build the project, with `make install` or `install.sh` or similar, you install the compiled files. If you want to test something locally, you might want to leave the final part out and so it's seperate.
2. You can use [GNU autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system).
3. Can you give specific examples? Makefiles do support wildcards and  they are used from time to time.
4. Makefile handles dependencies and automatic recompilation of only the needed files if you change something in a source file and then decide to rebuild the project. With a batch file you'd be recompiling everything, with Makefiles you're only compiling what was changed.