# Why are Makefiles in Linux so useful?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I want to know why makefiles in Linux are so useful (I mean in the practical sense). Why can't we just compile all our programs in the normal way?

Comment: Good question, worded poorly. Might want to try rephrasing it?

Comment: what is the "normal way"?

Comment: @helloworld922: I think the OP means something like "Compiling with an IDE".

Comment: @user567797: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388986/makefiles-configure-files-and-other-compilation-tools-how-do-they-work-wh).

Comment: In order to make a comparison, we really need to know what you mean by 'the normal way'. Otherwise, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Most language ecosystems have a way of *handling dependencies* and providing an *automated build system* -- even if not a "makefile". Consider Ant in Java or MSBuild for Visual Studio stuff. Makefile is just a widely adopted approach often used with C/C++ programs in *IX environments (although it will work for Java, Scala, etc.)

Comment: normal way means just typing the `rules` in a MakeFile on command line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Makefiles do so much work for you, and are frequently more powerful than people realize. Take the following simple makefile

```
 all: helloworld
```

that's one line, and (gnu make, at least) would know to run `cc -o helloworld helloworld.c` Then, as the project grows, you add one more rule:

```
helloworld: helloworld.o ui.o xml.o mailcomponent.o
   $(CC) -o $@ $@.c $^ $(LDLAGS)
```

and make knows to run

```
cc -c ui.c
cc -c xml.c
cc -c mailcomponent.c
cc -c helloworld.c
cc -o helloworld helloworld.o ui.o xml.o mailcomponent.o
```

Then say you want to optimize everything.

```
CFLAGS=-O2
```

at the beginning of the file takes care of you.

When the project gets larger, make keeps track of the files which have and haven't changed, preventing extraneous, and time-consuming re-compiles.

Makefiles are wonderful timesavers, and I haven't even touched on more advanced recipes.

Comment: Your example lacks auto-generated header dependencies. People following your example are going to struggle to get robust builds with it.

Comment: Makefiles don't have auto-generated header dependencies, that's one of the reasons automake exists

Comment: GNU Make auto-generates and uses header dependencies perfectly, [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793058/412080) for you, and [another](https://github.com/max0x7ba/atomic_queue/blob/master/Makefile).

Comment: automake exists for reasons unrelated to auto-generated header dependencies. If you claim otherwise, refer me to the source/origin of your claim.

Comment: Makefile examples without auto-generated header dependencies invariably result in corrupted builds and time wasted debugging them. This Makefile is even worse than that: it confuses linking with compiling piling `.o` and `.c` into one linker command without `$(LDFLAGS)`'; misses dependency of `helloworld` on `helloworld.c`, so that it doesn't recompile/relink when `helloworld.c` changes; has no concept of debug/release build modes. This is essentially a recipe for disaster, malinformation, to put it mildly.

Comment: Look this is a simplified example, I added the .c dep and I'll add ldflags. By automatic headers I thought you were referring to external dependencies not project headers, which is why I brought up autotools. I admit I didn't know about cc -MM though.

Answer (score 12):

The `normal way` for Linux is to use a makefile.

It evolved out of all the mistakes people made by compiling ever more complex applications by hand or with home-made scripts.  It is non-trivial to represent build dependencies for a complex project.  Make simply offers a standardized way to specify such dependencies and a tool to parse the dependencies and run associated build actions.

Even UI's that simplify/automate the build process for you use a make file or something similar behind the scenes.

**UPDATE**

In for those wondering about the automake comment, here are two differing views on the topic

http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool

http://www.scurrilous.com/blog/archives/2005/08/23/i-hate-automake/

Answer (score 10):

Because the normal way involves repetition and can easily be mistyped, especially when the commands get longer and more numerous, and more dependencies show up. Creating a makefile means that all one needs to do at the very least is run `make`, followed optionally by `make install`.

Answer (score 6):

A makefile is useful because (if properly defined) allows recompiling only what is needed when you make a change.

In a large project rebuilding the program can take some serious time because there will be many files to be compiled and linked and there will be documentation, tests, examples etc. When you work on the project and you make a little change it would be annoying having to wait to rebuild everything each time.

A makefile store a list "input" files, "output" files and "commands" needed to produce the output given the input. When you make a change to the project the command `make` will check the date of the input files with the date of the corresponding output files and if the input files has been changed it will recreate the corresponding output by running the command.

This is of course just a very rough description as make is much more sophisticated than this (topological sort, macro commands, parallel execution)... but it should give you an idea.

Rebuilding everything at each change would take too much time, and rebuilding manually only what is needed is error prone (if you forget to rebuild a piece you may end up thinking that a change you made is ok, while indeed it is breaking something that you simply did not recompile).

Note that today there is a plethora of build systems much more sophisticated than makefiles (that for example generate makefiles automatically by analyzing your platform and source code).

That those tools are a silver bullet or a solution looking for a problem is questionable (I'm biased on this because I hate build tools and they hate me... somehow their autodetect logic never works correctly on my machines).

Answer (score 3):

Complexity and time. A medium/big scale project contains hundreds of file with hundreds of dependencies. Do you want to remember them all? It is easy to make error when manually building the project. You could easily forget one dependency. And a big project may require several minutes to build. Make keeps track of time and recompile only those things that are necessary so that you don't need to wait several minutes during development.

The summary is make makes life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Normal way is to use makefiles.

It is useful because it was designed as a tool exactly for the purpose :-)
That's why it is also a normal way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also because make is 2 pass where relative order of directives does not matter.

In the normal way, dependencies must be taken care manually and we should always remember the order in which each line is executed before making any changes. Contrast this with, say, CFLAGS being added to all makefiles at the end using a script. You do not need to worry about the relative order of SOURCES and CFLAGS.