# Best practice for building a make file

Tags: makefile

Background:

I am relatively new to Make and I started building a makefile for my Othello game I recently built. My current makefile is relatively simple. Yet I am looking to refine it further and add a build and archive feature.

Question 1:
Why doesn't clean work?

Question 2:
For Archiving I plan on using

```
# tar cvzf *.o Othello
```

to archive, the .o and executable generated when compiled. Is this a good standard practice or is there a better way to do this?

Question 3:
For the build portion, I plan on running the executable using ./Othello is this best practice for build in a makefile?

The git repository is posted below thank you for your time

all: Othello

```
Othello: main.o Myothello.o space.o game.o
        clang++ main.o Myothello.o space.o game.o -o Othello

main.o: main.cc
        clang++ -c main.cc

game.o: game.cc
        clang++ -c game.cc

Myothello.o: Myothello.cc
            clang++ -c Myothello.cc

space.o: space.cc
        clang++ -c space.cc

clean:
rm -f *.o core *.core
rm MyOthello
```

Comment: A definite improvement. Now, in the `clean` rule, did you forget to begin the commands with TAB? And what do you mean, "why doesn't `clean` work"? What happens when you try it?

Comment: @Beta So when the make file runs it never goes into clean like it is not there so the out put I get is     clang++ -c main.cc    clang++ -c Myothello.cc    clang++ -c space.cc    clang++ -c game.cc    clang++ main.o Myothello.o space.o game.o -o Othello

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example makefile for you, tested on your github project.

Features:

1. Automatic dependency generation.
2. Automatic rebuild when `Makefile` is changed.
3. Debug/release builds in different directories. Debug build is the default, use `make BUILD=release` for release builds.
4. Supports `gcc` and `clang`. `gcc` is the default, use `make COMPILER=clang` for `clang`.
5. `clean` target works by removing the entire build directory.
6. `run` target to build and run, e.g. `make run_othello`.

Limitations:

1. Assumes that all source files are in the same directory. In a bigger project there are going to be multiple directories each with multiple build targets (executable, static or shared library). An isomorphic build directory structure is required to support this. Which is totally doable but requires more complexities in example `Makefile` below, so that it omitted for brevity.

When archiving you may like to archive only the source files and the makefile. No need to include any build artefacts (like object files, libraries and executables).

---

```
# ==== Begin prologue boilerplate.
all : # The canonical default target.
BUILD := debug
build_dir := ${CURDIR}/${BUILD}
exes := # Executables to build.
# ==== End prologue boilerplate.

# ==== Begin define executable othello.
exes += othello
objects.othello = main.o game.o Myothello.o space.o
-include ${objects.othello:%.o=${build_dir}/%.d} # Include auto-generated dependencies.
# ==== End define executable othello.

# ==== Begin define another executable.
# ... as for othello
# ==== End define another executable.

# ==== Begin rest of boilerplate.
SHELL := /bin/bash
COMPILER=gcc

CXX.gcc := /bin/g++
CC.gcc := /bin/gcc
LD.gcc := /bin/g++
AR.gcc := /bin/ar

CXX.clang := /bin/clang++
CC.clang := /bin/clang
LD.clang := /bin/clang++
AR.clang := /bin/ar

CXX := ${CXX.${COMPILER}}
CC := ${CC.${COMPILER}}
LD := ${LD.${COMPILER}}
AR := ${AR.${COMPILER}}

CXXFLAGS.gcc.debug := -Og -fstack-protector-all
CXXFLAGS.gcc.release := -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG
CXXFLAGS.gcc := -pthread -std=gnu++14 -march=native -W{all,extra,error} -g -fmessage-length=0 ${CXXFLAGS.gcc.${BUILD}}

CXXFLAGS.clang.debug := -O0 -fstack-protector-all
CXXFLAGS.clang.release := -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG
CXXFLAGS.clang := -pthread -std=gnu++14 -march=native -W{all,extra,error} -g -fmessage-length=0 ${CXXFLAGS.clang.${BUILD}}

CXXFLAGS := ${CXXFLAGS.${COMPILER}}
CFLAGS := ${CFLAGS.${COMPILER}}

LDFLAGS.debug :=
LDFLAGS.release :=
LDFLAGS := -fuse-ld=gold -pthread -g ${LDFLAGS.${BUILD}}
LDLIBS := -ldl

COMPILE.CXX = ${CXX} -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} -MD -MP ${CXXFLAGS} $(abspath $<)
PREPROCESS.CXX = ${CXX} -E -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $(abspath $<)
COMPILE.C = ${CC} -c -o $@ ${CPPFLAGS} -MD -MP ${CFLAGS} $(abspath $<)
LINK.EXE = ${LD} -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(filter-out Makefile,$^) $(LDLIBS)
LINK.SO = ${LD} -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(filter-out Makefile,$^) $(LDLIBS)
LINK.A = ${AR} rsc $@ $(filter-out Makefile,$^)

all : ${exes:%=${build_dir}/%} # Build all exectuables.

.SECONDEXPANSION:
# Build an executable.
${exes:%=${build_dir}/%} : ${build_dir}/% : $$(addprefix ${build_dir}/,$${objects.$$*}) Makefile | ${build_dir}
    $(strip ${LINK.EXE})

# Run an executable. E.g. make run_othello
${exes:%=run_%} : run_% : ${build_dir}/%
    @echo "---- running $< ----"
    /usr/bin/time --verbose $<

# Create the build directory on demand.
${build_dir} :
    mkdir $@

# Compile a C++ source into .o.
# Most importantly, generate header dependencies.
${build_dir}/%.o : %.cc Makefile | ${build_dir}
    $(strip ${COMPILE.CXX})

# Compile a C source into .o.
# Most importantly, generate header dependencies.
${build_dir}/%.o : %.c Makefile | ${build_dir}
    $(strip ${COMPILE.C})

clean :
    rm -rf ${build_dir}

.PHONY : clean all run_%

# ==== End rest of boilerplate.
```

Comment: I tried both of these makefiles and they both work great yours is an excellent resource and I am amazed how complicated makefiles can get. Thanks again for your help!! It is greatly appreciated

Comment: @DavidWisniewski Aw, thank you. In a bigger project there needs to be a layer of make macros to handle the tree structure of source files by building an isomorphic structure in the build folder. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Answer (score 0):

For a single folder project I built this Makefile
*Note the executable generated has been changed to Game

```
all: build archive

build: Game

Game: main.o Myothello.o space.o game.o
    clang++ main.o Myothello.o space.o game.o -o Othello

main.o: main.cc
    clang++ -c main.cc

game.o: game.cc
    clang++ -c game.cc

Myothello.o: Myothello.cc
    clang++ -c Myothello.cc

space.o: space.cc
    clang++ -c space.cc

clean:
    rm -f *.o core *.core

archive: main.cc game.cc Myothello.cc space.cc char.h  colors.h game.h 
space.h Myothello.h makefile
    tar -cf archive.tar main.cc game.cc Myothello.cc space.cc char.h  
    colors.h game.h space.h Myothello.h makefile
```

This works assuming all of your files are in the same directory
This is where I found my information

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_example.htm

https://www.tecmint.com/18-tar-command-examples-in-linux/

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html

ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_toc.html

Comment: Note that you do not need individual rules for each and every `.o` file. Use a  [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro). E.g. `%.o : %.cc ; clang++ -o $@ $<`. That is actually almost what [`make` does for you](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). But you won't get automatic header dependency generation with the built-in rules, or your rules above. This is why I provided my own rules that also generate dependencies, and this is why there is so much boilerplate.

Comment: @ Maxim Egorushkin so that is what a boilerplate does it repeats patterns in code?

Comment: It uses pattern rules to avoid repeating it for each and every source file. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules