# Writing Makefile for simple src, include, libs folders project

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I was writing a simple Makefile which will iterate thru .cpp files from ./src folder and include files from ./include folder. But getting "no input files" error. Could you please help me out for setting up.

I have below directory structure

```
./src     => It has main source file - Application.cpp and other applicationclass files like MyClass.cpp, Adapter.cpp. ...
./include => Include i.e. .h files, which has declarations.
./obj     => Where i am expecting to drop .o files
./bin     => Directory where i am expecting to drop executable
```

I tried with below Makefile but its giving me "no input files" error.
I am using some third party libraries which has include files which are sub folders inside "include" folder.

```
appname := Application

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -g

srcfiles := $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.cpp")

objects  := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(srcfiles))

all: $(appname)
    $(appname): $(objects)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(appname) $(objects) $(LDLIBS)

depend: .depend

.depend: $(srcfiles)
    rm -f ./.depend
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $^>>./.depend;

clean:
    rm -f $(objects)

dist-clean: clean
    rm -f *~ .depend

include .depend
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong or better way to compile this project.
Thank you for any help in this matter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793058/412080

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123431/building-multiple-executables-with-similar-rules/7321954#7321954

Comment: A few working examples for you.

Comment: Take a look here for a makefile that covers typical cases. It’s designed for Fortran but can be easily turned into C based project: http://www.owsiak.org/fortran-and-gnu-make/

Answer (score 1):

The directory is structure you outlined isn't well integrated into your makefile. Assuming that the makefile is in the top level directory, the line

```
srcfiles := $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.cpp")
```

doesn't find any files because of `-maxdepth 1`. A better approach is to use the builtin function

```
srcfiles := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
```

Second,

```
appname := Application
```

is later passed to the compiler as the `-o` argument. But as you said you want the binary to be in the `bin` directory, this should be adjusted to `bin/Application`. Finally,

```
all: $(appname)
    $(appname): $(objects)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(appname) $(objects) $(LDLIBS)
```

isn't well indented. You want an this:

```
all: $(appname)

$(appname): $(objects)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(appname) $(objects) $(LDLIBS)
```

and also make sure, that indentation are true tabs, not spaces. One additional note: you can generate the .d files containing header dependency information on the fly when passing `-MMD` to `g++`. This way, no separate rule/build step is required. Just make sure you `-include .depend` before the rule for building the object files.

Comment: Thank you very much. It trying to compile now - as getting some errors :)
I added "includes" variable to pass include files path and pass it with -I$(includes) parameter:


$(appname): $(objects)
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(includes) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(appname) $(objects) $(LDLIBS)

Yes, I am having "tabs" in my original script. Thx.

Comment: This make file creating .o files inside src folder itself.
Is there an easy way to move them to obj folder.

Comment: You can use this transformation: `objecs = $(srcfiles:%.cpp=myBuildDirectory/%.o)`. The dependency specification must then be `myBuildDirectory/%.o: src/%.cpp` and the build rule for that `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<`

Comment: I created separate thread for my question - as cannot post my modified Makefile here. Thread description is:
Adding INCLUDE, LIB and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Makefile