# Why does makefile not recognize defined library in C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I have a program in C that is compiled with gcc from a Makefile.
The makefile code:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -g -Wall -std=gnu99
LDFLAGS=#-pthread

SOURCES=ficheros_basico.c bloques.c mi_mkfs.c leer_SF.c #todos los .c
LIBRARIES=ficheros_basico.o bloques.o #todos los .o de la biblioteca del SF
INCLUDES=ficheros_basico.h bloques.h #todos los .h
PROGRAMS=mi_mkfs leer_SF
OBJS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJS) $(PROGRAMS)

    $(PROGRAMS): $(LIBRARIES) $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $@.o -o $@

%.o: %.c $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ $(PROGRAMS)
```

Then I get output:

```
gcc   mi_mkfs.o   -o mi_mkfs
/usr/bin/ld: mi_mkfs.o: en la función `main':
/home/ehe781/SOII_FS/mi_mkfs.c:9: referencia a `bmount' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ehe781/SOII_FS/mi_mkfs.c:12: referencia a `bwrite' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ehe781/SOII_FS/mi_mkfs.c:14: referencia a `initSB' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ehe781/SOII_FS/mi_mkfs.c:15: referencia a `initMB' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ehe781/SOII_FS/mi_mkfs.c:16: referencia a `initAI' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ehe781/SOII_FS/mi_mkfs.c:17: referencia a `bumount' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<integrado>: mi_mkfs] Error 1
```

when I execute the makefile.
I have defined those functions in `bloques.h`, and included this in `ficheros_basico.h`. Finally I included it in `mi_mkfs.c`, so as I see it, if you go inside of `ficheros_basico.h` you find the `bloques.h` include that has the defined functions.
Why does the makefile not recognize the function references?

PD:Sorry for the possibly messy question, but I didn't know how to explain it other way.

Comment: There are too many mistakes in your makefile. Adapt [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793058/412080) for your needs.

Comment: Where is bmount defined? Which file?

Comment: Do not define functions in header files. Define functions in source files (*.c), compile those into object files, and link the object files to make an executable.  If you truly "defined" the functions in bloques.h and included that file in mi_mkfs.c, then the function definitions would be available in the translation unit and `ld` would not complain.  I suspect you actually only declared the functions in the header (which is what you should do), but you have failed to declare `bloques.o` and `ficheros_basico.o` as a dependencies of `mi_mkfs`.

Comment: Are you confusing function *definitions* with function *declarations*?  It is declarations that belong in header files, but you still need exactly one definition of each function somewhere among all your sources.  Your error messages suggest that the definitions are not provided.  Note also that this hasn't much to do with `make` and makefiles in particular.

Comment: To debug your Makefile, call `make` with the option `-d`. It will print a lot, but valuable information why and what targets need to be made or not, resp.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by invalid indentation together with a built-in rule. Indented `$(PROGRAMS)` line does not define a target but is rather interpreted as part of recipe for `all`. Your `mi_mkfs` file is actually generated by an implicit rule, which can be verified with `make -p`:

```
mi_mkfs: mi_mkfs.o
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'mi_mkfs'
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has been updated.
#  Failed to be updated.
# automatic
# @ := mi_mkfs
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * := mi_mkfs
# automatic
# + := mi_mkfs.o
# automatic
# | :=
# automatic
# < := mi_mkfs.o
# automatic
# ^ := mi_mkfs.o
# automatic
# ? := mi_mkfs.o
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/19=5%
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

To make it work, indent your `$(PROGRAMS)` line correctly:

```
$(PROGRAMS): $(LIBRARIES) $(INCLUDES)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $@.o -o $@
```

Now the output is different:

```
$ make
gcc  ficheros_basico.o bloques.o  mi_mkfs.o -o mi_mkfs
```

since now your custom linking rule in invoked:

```
$ make -p
...
mi_mkfs: ficheros_basico.o bloques.o ficheros_basico.h bloques.h
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: ''
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has been updated.
#  Failed to be updated.
# automatic
# @ := mi_mkfs
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * :=
# automatic
# + := ficheros_basico.o bloques.o ficheros_basico.h bloques.h
# automatic
# | :=
# automatic
# < := ficheros_basico.o
# automatic
# ^ := ficheros_basico.o bloques.o ficheros_basico.h bloques.h
# automatic
# ? := ficheros_basico.o bloques.o ficheros_basico.h bloques.h
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/16=6%
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 14):
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $@.o -o $@
```