# How do I compile source files and headers that are on different directories with g++ in the makefile?

Tags: makefile, compilation, g++

My c++ project has the following structure:

```
packetSenderSim
|
|makefile
|
|<src>
|__ main.cpp
|__ testbench.cpp
|__ udp.cpp
|
|<headers>
|__ testbench.h
|__ udp.h
|__ toolbox.h
|
|<old>
|__ bitErrorModels.h
|__ efectivityTests.h
```

Before, I left all the "headers" and "src" files in the same directory and compiled with "g++ *.cpp -o exec". After some research I started to use "g++ -c *.cpp" "g++ *.o" instead, but it made my directory very polluted with .o files so I decided to structure the project this way. What I need to do is compile only the "src" and the "headers", the "old" file must be ignored (because it has old code that's not used anymore duh). I am a complete beginner in makefiles, first time writing one so if possible please explain the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: One example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793058/412080

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Comment: Where do you want the object files (`.o`) to go?