# Makefile objects in different folders with wildcard & headers (modular compile)?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, build, gnu-make

### UPDATE#04:

Got everything compiling. Will keep the answer concise so here are some intermediary steps.

Basically the Rules only partially worked because the **objects** were being made in their own folder still. After creating new local object **Rules** it compiled. However since they were now in their own directory the modular compile could not assemble the **objects** & work properly (programs will error when run).

The answer is a new **patsubst** pattern (of course), but I finally found one by trial & error that will allow output with **wildcard** + the original **Rules** + **Recipes** (for modular compiling with multiple **targets**). **See the answer below**.

### UPDATE#03:

Modular wildcard compile now works for the Client by trying patterns & rules in the order below & only changing them if they fail. However, I'm now unable to compile the Server from the Client objects & getting a bunch of **.c:(.text+0xb28): undefined reference to `My_Func_Call`** type errors. I've sorta given up on trying to move the objects to another path because Make just refuses to follow the rules properly or compile (will come back to that later).

Anyone know why objects/refs can't be reused now from the Client for the Server or any ideas on what might work?

```
# Pattern 1:
CODE = $(wildcard $(PATH)/*.c)
OBJS += $(CODE)

# Pattern 2:
CODE = $(wildcard $(PATH)/*.c)
CODE_OBJS = $(CODE:%.c=%.o)
OBJS += $(CODE_OBJS)

# Pattern 2 & Rule:
CODE = $(wildcard $(PATH)/*.c)
CODE_OBJS = $(CODE:%.c=%.o)
OBJS += $(CODE_OBJS)

$(BPATH)/%.o: $(PATH)/%.c $(PATH)/%.h $(COMMON_PATH)/%.h 
  %.o: %.c 
  $(DO_CC)
```

### UPDATE#02:

I continued to implement this pattern of wildcarding other sub dirs & just ignored where the objects are stored, but now the new compiled sub dirs seem to be causing conflicts. The previous header vars are missing (even though I changed nothing in the previous compiled code). This is caused by having multiple nested **%o: %c** rules I'm guessing (so that means I can't do anymore sub dirs argh).

I'm very open to someone pointing me towards some pattern or resources that might be in the area of this issue? Most of what I've seen are these simple Makefiles that have the same solutions over & over (non-modular compiles).

Otherwise, I think I'm going to go download GNU Make & start going line by line commenting it to figure out what is going on with the data. One thing is reading about stems & another is knowing what syntax or structure that Make actually needs to not break.

UPDATE#01:

Need a Makefile with objects in different folders & working with headers. I have it working in one path setup, but with a different path it's requiring more code to find the headers & not able to place the objects in a different folder.

This is basically what is happening in a minimal example -- any ideas?:

```
CODE00 = $(wildcard $(PATH00)/*.c)
OBJ00 = $(CODE00:%.c=%.o)

OBJS = $(OBJ00)

CODE = $(wildcard $(PATH)/*.c)
HEADER = $(wildcard $(PATH)/*.h) $(wildcard $(COMMON_PATH)/*.h) # Alt header.
#OBJ = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(CODE)) # Also works.
OBJ = $(CODE:%.c=%.o)

OBJS += $(OBJ)

############
# RULES:
############

# Works:
$(BPATH00)/%.o: $(PATH00)/%.c $(PATH00)/%.h $(PATH01)/%.h # Objs in folder/headers work.
    $(DO_CC)

# Broken:
$(BPATH)/%.o: $(PATH)/%.c $(PATH)/%.h $(COMMON_PATH)/%.h # Requires more before DO_CC?
  #%.o: %.c # Works but .o in source folder, fails without.
  #%.o: %.c ${HEADER} # Works but .o in source folder, fails without.
  $(BPATH)/%.o: %.c # Fails with missing header vars.
  #$(BPATH)/%.o: %.c ${HEADER} # Fails with missing header vars.
    $(DO_CC)

############
# LINK:
############

define DO_CC
gcc $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< 
endef
```

Comment: Could you tell us the names (and paths) of the files, and what you want Make to do?

Comment: What are the values for `PATH00`, `PATH`, `COMMON_PATH`, `PATH01`, `BPATH`, `BPATH00`.  Are the values all distinct?  For a given object file `$(BPATH00)/xyz.o`, why do you require two headers — both `$(PATH00)/xyz.h` and also `$(PATH01)/xyz.h`?  You comment about `D_CC` but it looks like you use `DO_CC`?  How many other typos are there in the file you show?

Comment: ^ Check the update above. I just uploaded the full compiling repo I'm using to learn Make.

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/cppfw/prorab . It will simplify your makefiles a lot and provide you with the functionality you are looking for. I.e. objects are placed in separate directory, header files dependencies are handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks, how is this different than cmake -- does it generate wildcards? I already know how to make simple Makefiles & ones that don't use wildcard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793058/412080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working **pattern** for **wildcard** & modular compiles with multiple **targets**.

NOTE: You will have to remove header **includes** or conflicting **%.o: %o.c** **Rules** needed for same folder **objects**. Otherwise it will cause lots of weird missing target errors that change when you alter the **Rule** order (which just wastes your time & is confusing).

```
HOST_CODE      := $(wildcard $(HOST_PATH)/*.c)
HOST_OBJECTS    = $(patsubst $(HOST_PATH)/%.c, $(HOST_BPATH)/%.o, $(HOST_CODE))
CLIENT_OBJECTS  = $(patsubst $(HOST_PATH)/%.c, $(CLIENT_BPATH)/%.o, $(HOST_CODE))

# Or to append:

HOST_CODE      := $(wildcard $(HOST_PATH)/*.c)
HOST_OBJECTS   += $(patsubst $(HOST_PATH)/%.c, $(HOST_BPATH)/%.o, $(HOST_CODE))
CLIENT_OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(HOST_PATH)/%.c, $(CLIENT_BPATH)/%.o, $(HOST_CODE))

# Rules (includes/headers will break your compile):

$(HOST_BPATH)/%.o: $(HOST_PATH)/%.c
    $(DO_HOST_CC)

$(CLIENT_BPATH)/%.o: $(HOST_PATH)/%.c
    $(DO_CLIENT_CC)
```

You won't need header include **Rules**. But if you want to test to see if your headers are working I recommend this non-conflicting pattern (many patterns easily conflict & break your **Makefile**, so you need to be **VERY** careful):

```
INCLUDES = $(shell find . -name '*.d')

include $(INCLUDES)
```